# Оптимизировать код

Tags: php, ооп, ssh

хотелось бы узнать мнение специалистов в области PHP. Интересует данный фрагмент кода:

```
class SecureShell
{
public function ssh($ip, $login, $password, $argument)
{
  $connection = ssh2_connect($ip, 22);

  if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, $login, $password)) {
      $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $argument);
      stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
      $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
      return $result = stream_get_contents($stream_out);

    }
}

}
```

Каким образом данный фрагмент кода можно максимально использовать в виде ООП? Если можно, то живой пример SOLID кода. Максимально оптимизированный и логичный, по "феншую" если хотите. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что вас смущает?

Comment: Да - поясните пожалуйста для каких целей - вы будете его ещё где то использовать или хранить какие то состояния

Comment: не хватает ssh2_disconnect и еще есть уязвимость - отсутствует функция ssh2_fingerprint()

Comment: @Manitikyl, нет предела совершенству. Как выяснилось комментарием ниже, у меня даже в этом мизерном клочке кода есть уязвимость. Сейчас еще замечания появятся.

Comment: Ну если вам нужны замечание по этому коду - то вот они - если предполагается использовать этот класс как есть, т.е не наследоваться от него, то рекомендуется использовать public static function - это сократит использование кода на 1 строчку и ускорит выполнение в цикле. Также нет проверок на входные значения - например $ip. Нету сценария поведения программы если: некорректные данные, если не удалось подключиться, или на каком то этапе что то пошло не так  - тот кто будет пользоваться этим кодом не поймет - ошибка произошла из за того что удаленный сервер отключен или накосячил с $argument

Comment: @Mcile, спасибо за дельный совет. Сейчас попробую сделать корректнее.

Comment: @Mcile, вот что у меня получилось https://pastebin.com/cYK2PfG0